# How to Synchronize Dropbox PDFs to Kindle DX?

Tags: pdf, sync, dropbox, kindle, ereader

### Background

I'm strongly considering the purchase of a Kindle DX for PDF reading to save my eyes from LCD strain.

I currently sync a folder of PDFs on Dropbox to my iPad via an app called GoodReader.

### Goal

I would like to sync the contents of the same DropBox folder to the Kindle DX so that I can update my PDF collection in one place for both readers.

I'd prefer to not have to do anything additionally to get the files onto the Kindle (i.e. I don't want to have to e-mail myself a file, though if that could be automated away once I wouldn't mind).

### Question

Is there a process that exists to allow me to update DropBox and have the contents automatically synced to the Kindle DX?

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

Answer (score 3):

I found two options to do that:

1. Using [WappWolf](http://wappwolf.com) following this [guide](http://wappwolf.com/dropboxautomator/learnmore).
2. Using [if this then that](http://www.ifttt.com) with a [recipe](http://ifttt.com/recipes/7731) that checks a folder and sends its contents to the kindle mail.

Comment: These are both great options. Thank you, Henry! One question I have is what to do about all the books that are already in this folder. Will any of these allow me to apply the rules I create to existing items? I can't seem to find an answer on that. I have ~100 that I'd like to sync without re-adding as they're already synced elsewhere..

Comment: I don't know how to do it with your existing files. You could try copying them to another temporary "watched" folder. Dropbox detects the files already exist so they won't be uploaded again.

Answer (score 0):

I use the quickoffice PDF reader on Android and have Kindle installed on my Android. Quickoffice offers me the  to send files to the Kindle via 'sharing' menu.

Answer (score 0):

I give a simple solution to this problem. Checkout this:

https://code.google.com/p/kindle-file-synchronizer/

Comment: Link only answers can become a problem. Its OK if the link supplements information, but it should probably not be the answer. Perhaps you could edit the question and add more substance, like how to use it to synchronize.